# Aframe cycle through a-sky image source on button click

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to cycle through over panoramic images set as `a-sky`, using the forward and back buttons. But I'm struggling with the js logic. Any help is appreciated. The below example uses 3 images in the array, but in practice it'll have hundreds.

```js
  function goNext() {

    var zerod = 0;
    var images = ["https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg", 
                  "https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/composite/lake.jpg", 
                  "https://l13.alamy.com/360/PWNBM9/testing-new-cameralens-combination-in-my-garden-in-aarhus-denmark-PWNBM9.jpg"]

    function nextimage() {
    console.log(zerod)
      $("#sky").attr("src", images[zerod])
      zerod = (zerod < images.length + 1) ? ++zerod : 0
    }
    nextimage();
  };
  
    function goBack() {

    var zerod = 0;
    var images = ["https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg", 
                  "https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/composite/lake.jpg", 
                  "https://l13.alamy.com/360/PWNBM9/testing-new-cameralens-combination-in-my-garden-in-aarhus-denmark-PWNBM9.jpg"]

    function previmage() {
    console.log(zerod)
      $("#sky").attr("src", images[zerod])
      zerod = (zerod < images.length - 1) ? ++zerod : 0
    }
    previmage();
  };
```

```css
.menu {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 15px;
}

.menu a {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: tahoma;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>  
</head>
    
<body>
        <div class="menu">
        <!--<br>-->
        <a id="forward" onClick="goNext()">Forward</a>
        <!--<br>-->
        <a id="back" onClick="goBack()">Back</a>
        <!--<br>-->
        <a id="vr" onclick="document.querySelector('a-scene').enterVR()">VR</a>
        </div>

    <a-scene image-toggle vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
           
    <a-assets>
      <img id="skybox" src="https://l13.alamy.com/360/PWNBM9/testing-new-cameralens-combination-in-my-garden-in-aarhus-denmark-PWNBM9.jpg">
    </a-assets>
        
      <a-sky id="sky" src="#skybox"></a-sky>
        <a-camera id="camera" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false">
        </a-camera>
    </a-scene>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all both `goNext()` and `goBack()` set `zerod` to 0;

---

Second of all you want to change the index before setting the source.
Imagine calling `goNext()` and `goBack()`:

```
// goNext()
$("#sky").attr("src", images[zerod])              // zerod is 0 here
zerod = (zerod < images.length + 1) ? ++zerod : 0 // zerod i 1 here

// goBack()
$("#sky").attr("src", images[zerod]) // zerod is 1 here! Nothing changes!
zerod = (zerod < images.length - 1) ? ++zerod : 0
```

`goBack()` does nothing in this case if you click it after `goNext()`

---

Last but not least - the conditions:

```
// goNext()
// three images, but you check if the index is less then 4?
zerod = (zerod < images.length + 1) ? ++zerod : 0           

// goBack()
// you increase the index? thought you should be going back
zerod = (zerod < images.length - 1) ? ++zerod : 0
```

Should look like this:

```
// goNext()
// switch to 0 when we're at the last image (2nd index for three images)
zerod = (zerod < images.length - 1) ? ++zerod : 0  
    
// goBack()
// decrease the index. change to the last image when at the first one
zerod = (zerod <= 0) ? --zerod : images.length - 1;
```

---

Check it out with these three points applied:

```js
var zerod = 0;
var images = ["https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg",
  "https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/composite/lake.jpg",
  "https://l13.alamy.com/360/PWNBM9/testing-new-cameralens-combination-in-my-garden-in-aarhus-denmark-PWNBM9.jpg"
]

function goNext() {
  zerod = (zerod < images.length - 1) ? ++zerod : 0;
  console.log(zerod)
  $("#sky").attr("src", images[zerod])
}

function goBack() {
  zerod = (zerod != 0) ? --zerod : images.length -1;
    console.log(zerod)
  $("#sky").attr("src", images[zerod])
};
```

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 15px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <!--<br>-->
    <a id="forward" onClick="goNext()">Forward</a>
    <!--<br>-->
    <a id="back" onClick="goBack()">Back</a>
    <!--<br>-->
    <a id="vr" onclick="document.querySelector('a-scene').enterVR()">VR</a>
  </div>

  <a-scene image-toggle vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">

    <a-assets>
      <img id="skybox" src="https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg">
    </a-assets>

    <a-sky id="sky" src="#skybox"></a-sky>
    <a-camera id="camera" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false">
    </a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

---

Even better if you turn it into a [custom component](https://aframe.io/docs/1.3.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html#sidebar):

```css
.menu {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 15px;
}

.menu a {
  display: block;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  color: white;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: tahoma;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("image-changer", {
    init: function() {
      // grab the elements
      const nextbtn = document.getElementById("forward");
      const backbtn = document.getElementById("back");
      // react to the clicks
      nextbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.index = (this.index < this.images.length - 1) ? ++this.index : 0;
        this.changeImage()
      })
      backbtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        this.index = (this.index != 0) ? --this.index : this.images.length - 1;
        this.changeImage()
      })
      // initial index and images values
      this.index = 0;
      this.images = ["https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/boilerplate/panorama/puydesancy.jpg",
        "https://aframe.io/aframe/examples/showcase/composite/lake.jpg",
        "https://l13.alamy.com/360/PWNBM9/testing-new-cameralens-combination-in-my-garden-in-aarhus-denmark-PWNBM9.jpg"
      ]
      this.changeImage();
    },
    changeImage: function() {
      this.el.setAttribute("src", this.images[this.index])
    }
  })
</script>
<div class="menu">
  <!--<br>-->
  <a id="forward">Forward</a>
  <!--<br>-->
  <a id="back">Back</a>
  <!--<br>-->
  <a id="vr" onclick="document.querySelector('a-scene').enterVR()">VR</a>
</div>

<a-scene image-toggle vr-mode-ui="enabled: false">
  <a-sky id="sky" image-changer></a-sky>
  <a-camera id="camera" look-controls="pointerLockEnabled: false">
  </a-camera>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: You've done it again sir! A very concise explanation.
What do you recommend if page crashes after cycling through a few hundred images?

Comment: I'd try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69433617/2425787) approach, let me know if it helps, or if it needs elaborating